# Retrofit 2: File upload never finishes

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to upload an arbitrary number of files to a server. When I run the request it just does some work indefinitely. No exception is thrown, no callback method is called. I am using it with RxJava. So, onSubscribe() gets called when I start request and onNext(), onError(),  onComplete() never gets called.

**EDIT:**
Request works if I send only "msg" message without any file and I can see it on my server.
Here is my code:

```
@POST("some/address/")
@Multipart
Observable<ResponseBody> sendMessages(@Part("msg") String message,
                                      @Part("companion") Integer companion,
                                      @Part("description") RequestBody description,
                                      @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files);
```

Method in model:

```
public Observable<ResponseBody> sendMessage(String message, int companion, RequestBody description, List<MultipartBody.Part> multiParts) {
    return mService.sendMessages(message, companion, description, multiParts).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Meethod in presenter:

```
void sendMessage(String message, int companion, List<Uri> fileUris, Context context) {
    List<MultipartBody.Part> multiParts = new ArrayList<>();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    for (int i = 0; i < fileUris.size(); i++) {
        Uri uri = fileUris.get(i);
        multiParts.add(createMultipart(uri, contentResolver));
    }
    RequestBody description = createPartFromString("hello, this is description speaking");
    Observable<ResponseBody> observable = mModel.sendMessage(message, companion, description, multiParts);
    observable.subscribe(new Observer<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            showProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(ResponseBody value) {
            if (getView() != null) {
                getView().dataLoaded();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            hideProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            hideProgress();
        }
    });
}


@NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part createMultipart(Uri fileUri, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    File file = new File(fileUri.toString());
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

Comment: can you add a log? try to add logging interceptor, it might reveals what happens at network level

Comment: Actually nothing notable happens.It show the request:  D/OkHttp: --> POST https://address/to/server http/1.1 (870-byte body). However, request works if I just send "msg" without any file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging around, I found out that this behaviour happens when File is not retrieved from Uri correctly. I used this: `File file = new File(fileUri.toString());` I have used FileUtils as suggested by the tutorial on FutureStudio about file uploading.